# Unable to change ownership from root to my user

Tags: sudo, ext4, chmod, chown

I am trying to change files so my user owns them, instead of root.  I've searched this forum.  I am getting the same error several hundred times for each command.

This syntax

```
sudo chown -v -R rpiggott:rpiggott /media/rpiggott/782f830c-c965-4960-8ed2-f8433bfaf8ce/Laptop/PhpstormProjects
```

is giving me this error message:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/media/rpiggott/782f830c-c965-4960-8ed2-f8433bfaf8ce/Laptop/PhpstormProjects': Read-only file system
```

This syntax

```
sudo find /media/rpiggott/782f830c-c965-4960-8ed2-f8433bfaf8ce/Laptop/PhpstormProjects -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

is giving me this error message:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/rpiggott/782f830c-c965-4960-8ed2-f8433bfaf8ce/Laptop/PhpstormProjects/mypainmanagementtracker.net/public/layout': Read-only file system
```

I've also tried the approach of remount

```
sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw /dev/sdb1
```

Which produces the error message

```
mount: /media/rpiggott/782f830c-c965-4960-8ed2-f8433bfaf8ce not mounted or bad option
```

The command

```
sudo parted -l
```

Gives the result

```
Model: WD My Passport 0741 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  reiserfs
```

Comment: I hadn't considered searching for the external hard disk being read only

Comment: It fixed itself after 2 reboots.  How did the hard drive get marked read-only?  Any theories?